# archlinux running gnome

Tags: linux, login, themes, wireless-networking, kde

I am new here, don't know if I can even turn to help here about this subject but I just installed archlinux on my laptop and installed gdm on it, I was wondering a couple of things.

1. on boot my gdm does not start automatically although i have added it daemon, and dbus must be run manually as well. Also, the filesystem check fails because it says that it cant find /dev/sdb4 but that does not exist even, the system is on sda4, can you change the fsck location?
2. i was wondering as well if it is possible to have a kde loginscreen and still run gnome DE, cause i really like this: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/KDMretina?content=78261 , and i cant even find it which leads me to my third question.
3. does anyone have or know how to get and install this:
   http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/KDMretina?content=78261
4. my wireless network is kinda hard to configure, as i am new to config in linux, i have to use sudo wifi-menu every time i need to connect to the internet. tried networkmanager but something always goes wrong, any suggestions?
5. i have tried banshee, amarok but i cant get the music to play, i added them and everything but on double click .. nothing happens

sorry if this is the wrong place for my questions
please be forgiving :P

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed the right place for your question. Unfortunately you have not asked one question but many unrelated ones. Please separate each subject into a different question. Check out the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) and [this](http://meta.superuser.com/q/1815/151431) thread on meta for guidelines.

Now, for your questions regarding GDM. Yes you can use KDM (the KDE login manager) instead of GDM. The login manager is independent of the Desktop Environment you use, so you can use KDM to log into GNOME with no problem.

For more information on installing KDM and its themes, see [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDM) of the ARCH wiki.

Please post your questions on wifi, music, dbus and fsck (hint, check out `/etc/fstab`) separately.

Comment: thanks for your answer i may do as you suggested but i have been reading a whole lot more on linux and i like to experiment.